# Variable in path

Tags: variables, path

Im having a bit of problem with variable in path

```
Log="/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud/$Date/s301"
```

where

```
Date=$Year"-"$Month"-"$Day
Year=$(date '+%Y') 
Month=$(date '+%m')
Day=$(date '+%d')
```

When trying to echo log i got

```
/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud//s301`
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Please provide an indication of the language / program that this script is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language are you using?

Assuming bash (could be given your syntax), your code works. Well, given that you write it in the correct order:

```
#!/bin/bash

Year=$(date '+%Y') 
Month=$(date '+%m')
Day=$(date '+%d')

Date=$Year"-"$Month"-"$Day
Log="/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud/$Date/s301"

echo "$Day"
echo "$Month"
echo "$Year"
echo "$Date"
echo "$Log"
```

Output:

```
26
05
2017
2017-05-26
/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud/2017-05-26/s301
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Year, Month and Day variables are not set when you are assigning Date variable.

It should be:

```
Year=$(date '+%Y') 
Month=$(date '+%m')
Day=$(date '+%d')
Date=$Year-$Month-$Day
Log="/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud/$Date/s301"
```

or

```
Date=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
Log="/appl/xxx/utpd/bin/ud/$Date/s301"
```